# Zuul service name exposed instead of route path only

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a spring-cloud project with zuul gateway.

I told the gateway to route any request from /book-api/** to book-service (rest) by specifying property below in gateway.properties:

```
zuul.routes.book-service.path=/book-api/**
```

But it leads me to duplicate api. I able to access same service from both /book-service/getBook and book-api/getBook paths rather than access it from /book-api/getBook path only.

Should I made filter for hiding /book-service/** path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to add the below property

```
zuul.ignored-services=*
```

All services are added into Zuul routes automatically as default. You can disable it with the above property.

You can find more detail in 'Embedded Zuul Reverse Proxy' section of the [document](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.3.4.RELEASE/)

Comment: I have tried this before from this [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_router_and_filter_zuul) page, it doesn't work. Also tried with zuul.ignoredServices. Am I missing something? I will try to follow the documentation, by using application.yml.

Comment: Here's the entire config files ([github](https://github.com/smsidki/microservice/blob/master/application-config/gateway-service.properties))

Comment: @Sidqi there was a typo in my response. I edited my response. asterisk without double quote. zuul.ignored-services=*

Comment: You are using properties file instead of yml. If you put value with double quote, double quotes are also treated as a part of value.

Comment: how about using consul key/value config? I added key config/gateway-service/zuul.ignored-services and * as its value. But it doesn't work.